# addControl() throwing "not a function" error in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I made a function to play with the `addControl()` method in Angular forms and no matter how I attempt to apply it or where I apply it I get an error telling me `(something).addControl() is not a function`.

I have these variables defined in my class

```
demoA:string = 'name';
demoB:Array<string> = ['city', 'state'];
demoC:FormGroup<any>= {};
```

The function looks like this

```
loadStuff(){
    let a = this.demoA;
    let b = this.demoB;
    let c = this.demoC;
    let ab:Array<string> = [];
    let cc:FormGroup= {};

    ab.push(a);
    b.forEach(bb => { ab.push(bb)});
    console.log(ab);

    cc.addControl(a, new FormControl('') );

    console.log(cc);

}
```

I call it in the constructor if that makes any difference to you.  I was originally trying to implement it inside of a `forEach()` method but got that same error which is when I decided to try it on one single variable.  I have both `Forms` and `ReactiveFormsModule` successfully imported into the app module working properly on other things.  I haven't come across anything in Angular's docs stating you need to import anything else into the component, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `cc` has the type `FormGroup` but it's defined as an `Object`, you have to define it as a `FormGroup`.

```
let cc:FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
```

or use the `FormBuilder` from `@angular/forms`

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
// ...
let cc: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({});
```